# Given a single taped deterministic turing machine what's the least amount of calculations needed in order to receive the language

Tags: turing-machines

Given a single taped deterministic turing machine what's the least amount of calculations needed in order to receive the language $L_k=${$0,1$}$^*0${$0,1$}$^{k-1}$.

My intuition says that i'll need at least $n+k$ calculations.

I will start at the leftmost digit, and go through whole the tape until i reach blank on the rightmost corner of the tape.

Then i'll create {$\sigma_1,...\sigma_{k-1}$} new alphabets in order to the 'count' the digits, Once i'm done using $\sigma_{k-1}$ digits i know i should reach $0$, If i don't i reject.

The solution above has 2 problem:

1. Since {$0,1$}$^*$ can be infinite, The machine above will never reach accept state.
2. I'm not sure it's the most efficent way.

Help please.

Comment: I assume you mean letters rather than alphabets? You can do it in $n$ steps if you allow $O(2^k)$ states.

Comment: 1. Well, $L_k$ is indeed an infinite set of words, as $\{0,1\}^*$ is infinite, but each actual member of it (i.e. a $0$-$1$-word having $0$ as its $k$th digit from the right) is actually *finite*. In other words, *all inputs are considered finite* so you don't have to worry about infinite words (whence indeed the machine would never reach state $\sigma_1$...).

Comment: As for objection (1), $\{0,1\}^*$ cannot be infinite. It is unbounded, but it doesn't match any infinite string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to remember the last $k$ digits in the state. You also have to deal with the states before you get to $k$ digits. Then when you get the the vacant entry on the strip, the process halts, and either succeeds or fails based on the state - which encodes the last $k$ bits. This actually requires a Turing machine with $2^{k+1}$ states, including the final state and the preliminary states.

For example, if $k=2$, you'd have the following states:

$$e,0,1,00,01,10,11,f$$

Comment: Assume $k=2$ and we input $110101$. I guess, it starts on state $e$, but when will it pass to state '0'? At the first or second zero?
It feels like it's rather a nondeterministic machine..

Comment: The states with that input are: $e\to 1\to 11\to 10\to 01\to 10\to 01\to f$. The last step, when we read the "empty" cell, indicates success. If you got an empty cell in states $00$ or $01$ then you'd succeed, otherwise, you'd fail.

Comment: In particular, it will never be in state $0$.

Comment: I don't get it yet. I need to create $2^{k-1}$ states in order to remember the different permutations of: {$0,1$}$^{k-1}$. How do i actually 'deal' with the states before the last $k$ digits? How can i use the remembered permutations in my favour?

Comment: A Turing machine is a set of states and a set of actions given the states and the contents of the current cell. If your state is $01$ at some point, and you next read $1$, then you move to state $11$ and move the head to the right. If you next read $0$, your state changes to $10$ and you move the head to the right. If your head is empty, then the last two digits are $01$, and you've got a match, because $0$ is the first digit of $01$.

Comment: Got it, Thanks. Really clever solution.